# Implement streaming webcam with HTML iframe iOS setMessageLoggingBlock: called

Tags: html, ios, iframe, uiwebview, nsurl

I'm happy that I've succeed to display my webcam on my UIWebView, but console writes errors :

```
BundoranSurfCo[5798:145001] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <Webcam: 0x7929db30>.
Mar  9 15:45:28 MacBook-Pro-de-Vincent.local rtcreporting[5798] <Info>: logging starts...
Mar  9 15:45:28 MacBook-Pro-de-Vincent.local rtcreporting[5798] <Debug>: setMessageLoggingBlock: called
```

**This error appears when I'm tapping on the video for showing in full screen...**

My code is :
Webcam.m :

```
NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]URLForResource:@"myHTML" withExtension:@"html"];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl];
[_webView loadRequest:requestURL];
```

MyHTML.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html><head>
    <title>Bundoran Surf Co</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

        <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
             (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
             m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
             })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

             ga('create', 'UA-40971454-1', 'myipstream.com');
             ga('send', 'pageview');

            </script><script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/bkfmKFnaEeKE5iIACp8kUw.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style><script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/jwpsrv.js"></script><script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/sharing.js"></script><script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/jwpsrv_frq.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style></head>

<body>
    <div id="banner"></div>

    <div id="my-video"></div>


    <div id="playerKQLqhEDY5doy_wrapper" style="position: relative; display: block; width: 300px; height: 300px;"><a id="beforeswfanchor0" href="#playerKQLqhEDY5doy" tabindex="0" title="Flash start" style="border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);display:block;height:1px;margin:-1px;outline:none;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;width:1px;" data-related-swf="playerKQLqhEDY5doy"></a><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/jwplayer.flash.swf" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#000000" id="playerKQLqhEDY5doy" name="playerKQLqhEDY5doy" class="jwswf swfPrev-beforeswfanchor0 swfNext-afterswfanchor0" tabindex="0"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"></object><a id="afterswfanchor0" href="#playerKQLqhEDY5doy" tabindex="0" title="Flash end" style="border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);display:block;height:1px;margin:-1px;outline:none;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;width:1px;" data-related-swf="playerKQLqhEDY5doy"></a><div id="playerKQLqhEDY5doy_aspect" style="display: none;"></div><div id="playerKQLqhEDY5doy_jwpsrv" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 10;"></div><div id="playerKQLqhEDY5doy_sharing" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 11;"></div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer('playerKQLqhEDY5doy').setup({
                                             playlist: [{
                                                        image: "http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/homepage_offers1.jpg",
                                                        sources: [{
                                                                  file: "rtmp://144.76.75.86/live/bundoransurfco"
                                                                  },{
                                                                  file: "http://144.76.75.86/hls/bundoransurfco/playlist.m3u8"
                                                                  }]
                                                        }],
                                             height: 300,
                                             primary: "flash",
                                             width: 300,
                                             controls: true, 
                                             autostart: true,
                                             sharing: true

                                             });
        </script>
    <br>

    <style type="text/css">
        #photo {
            position:relative;
            bottom:20px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="photo" align="middle">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://myipstream.com/images/bundoran.jpeg" width="150" height="80" alt="@ Surf Co">
    </a><a href="#" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://myipstream.com/images/seasessions.jpeg" width="150" height="80" alt="Bundoran Sea Sessions"></a></div>


    </body></html>
```

(copy/paste from my main website, and just changed height & width).

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed** :

These *rtcreporting* logs only appear when running the iOS simulator. Everything works fine on a device.